# Exception launching Chrome: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am seeing this exception when launching Chrome Browser using RemoteWebDriver.
I have tried getting the latest versions of selenium server and chromedriver, but with no luck.
I seem to run out of ides. 
Has anyone encountered this error and has found a solution.

```
12:48:18.012 INFO - Registering the node to hub :http://mydomain:4444/grid/regi
ster
12:50:38.741 INFO - Executing: [new session: {platform=ANY, browserName=chrome,
chromeOptions={args=[--user-data-dir=C:\Use..., version=}] at URL: /session)
12:50:38.771 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{platform=ANY, brow
serName=chrome, chromeOptions={args=[--user-data-dir=C:\Users\vidder\AppData\Loc
al\Vidder_Inc\SDP Browser\userdata, --start-maximized --profile-directory=Defaul
t], extensions=[]}, version=}]
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.4.226107) on port 29990
12:51:00.234 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'vidder-PC3', ip: '10.10.104.69', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.ar
ch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSessi
on.java:176)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSessio
n.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(Defaul
tSession.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(De
faultDriverSessions.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSessio
n.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConf
ig.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpRemoteConfig.handleRequest(
JsonHttpRemoteConfig.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverS
ervlet.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.
java:167)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet
.java:139)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.jav
 a:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler
.java:677)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.j
ava:568)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:914)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)

    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:9
86)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.
java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationT
argetException
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'vidder-PC3', ip: '10.10.104.69', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.ar
ch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.callConstructo
r(DefaultDriverFactory.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(De
faultDriverFactory.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(
DefaultSession.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(
DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession
.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.callConstructo
r(DefaultDriverFactory.java:62)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed
to start: exited normally
```

Comment: I am launching Chrome with this profile defined in the code.

Comment: String userProfile= "C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\Test";
     String profileDirectory = "Default";
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     options.addArguments("--user-data-dir="+userProfile);
     options.addArguments("--start-maximized --profile          directory="+profileDirectory);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);       
    webdriver1 = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.10.104.69:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);         webdriver1.get("http://www.yahoo.com");

Comment: Wanted to share the solution in case anyone has the same issue. This exception occurs because the profile that Selenium is launching was used by the application that is being automated. So pointing the user-directory of chrome options to another folder that has the same profile helped resolve this problem.